# Helping fetching text from MySQL database into drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql

I need help fetching a column of month names and displaying them in a drop down menu. I've tried a million different ways with no luck. Your help will be appreciated.

```
<?php 
    $sqlm="SELECT`Month` FROM `ActualsInput`";
    $resultm=mysqli_query($con,$sqlm);

    /// fecthing into
    $MonthMenu=mysqli_fetch_array($resultm,MYSQLI_NUM);

    // Print the result
    echo '<select name="city"><OPTION>'; 
    echo "Select an option</OPTION>"; 

    foreach ($MonthMenu as $g) {
        echo '<OPTION value="' . $g . '">' . $g . '</OPTION>'; 
    } 

    echo '</SELECT>';

    mysqli_free_result($resultm);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: there are multiple places this could be failing, could you tell us where the issue is

Comment: `print_r($g)`. Array?

Comment: Just a thought you can just use the PHP date function [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: "*with no luck*" - Tells us nothing about what's going wrong. Is it syntax error? Not the expected output? Is it too slow? Does the keyboard freeze when you try to program? Does your computer not have power going into it?

Comment: Its not giving me an output at all

Comment: Its not giving me an output, its showing the drop down menu but not giving me the values, I want it to give me the month names to populate the list

Comment: debugging 101: `print_r($MonthMenu);`

Comment: You should include a little more of HTML code, it could be an issue with the html and not the php itself.

Comment: Where is your `$con`? Did you include your established connection to your database?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots to be considered why you are not getting your desired results:

## Database Connection

First, did you include your database connection to that specific page?

```
$con = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY PARAMETERS */
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error;
}
```

## Case Sensitive

Remember that database, table, and column names are case sensitive, so better check your `Month` and `ActualsInput` if they are correct. What you can do is to run your query at the back-end (PhpMyAdmin), if it will return some results:

```
SELECT `Month` FROM `ActualsInput`
```

You can also refer to the other **error checking** mentioned in the comment section of your post.

## Fetching

You can also try the more standard fetching of data from your database:

```
<?php 

    /* INCLUDE HERE YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION */

    echo '<select name="city">
              <option>Select an option</option>'; 

    $sqlm = "SELECT `Month` FROM `ActualsInput`";
    $resultm = mysqli_query($con, $sqlm);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultm)){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['Month'].'">'.$row['Month'].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';

?>
```

## Prepared Statement

You would also like to consider `mysqli_*`'s [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

```
<?php 

    /* INCLUDE HERE YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION */

    echo '<select name="city">
              <option>Select an option</option>';

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `Month` FROM `ActualsInput`");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($month);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo '<option="'.$month.'">'.$month.'</option>';
    }
    $stmt->close();

    echo '</select>';

?>
```

If you can provide more information about your problem, that could make us help you easier.